# Android NDK, Error:(165, 0) Cause: ndk-build binary cannot be found

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, react-native

I'm trying to run the react-native ReactAndroid project with AndroidStudio. However I get this NDK error.

`Error:(165, 0) Cause: ndk-build binary cannot be found, check if you've set $ANDROID_NDK environment variable correctly or if ndk.dir is setup in local.properties`

I have downloaded the android NDK from here http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/ndk/downloads/index.html

`echo $ANDROID_NDK` gives `/Users/lu/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r10e`

inside local.properties I have: 
`ndk.dir=/Users/username/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r10e`

I'm using Android Studio 1.4

Answer (score 19):

I got this same error when running the UI explorer app for React Native on Android. If you are on a Mac here is what worked for me:

`$ brew install android-ndk`

`$ echo 'export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-ndk' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Restart your terminal

Make sure you have an emulator running then:

```
cd react-native
./gradlew :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug
./packager/packager.sh
```

The initial build will take sometime

Comment: Why there is everywhere an explanation about how to set up the sdk and setting the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` but not for the ndk. Well, there is a pretty good exmplanation but there is nowhere indicated that you have to set a variable called `ANDROID_NDK_HOME`. Does someone has to know that or did I just search wrong? Thanks @Athman

Comment: React native does not work with the latest ndk, I had to run "brew install homebrew/versions/android-ndk-r10e" then "echo 'export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-ndk-r10e' >> ~/.bash_profile"

Answer (score 7):

Try copying your local.properties file in the top level directory of your react-native checkout.

Answer (score 1):

#### Android NDK is moved to Cask , so try this command instead :

```
brew cask install android-ndk
```

#### Then :

```
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-ndk"
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who has same error on Ubuntu.

I had this problem. Android NDK was installed and `$ANDROID_NDK` variable was set, but I got same error (something like `ndk-build binary cannot be found or is not executable`) when trying to build React Native [Movies app example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/Movies) with command
`./gradlew :Examples:Movies:android:app:installDebug`.
Andoid NDK folder was located in `/opt` under `root` user and `root` group.

I moved Android NDK folder under `~/Android/` and set owner and group to my user.
And I changed `$ANDROID_NDK` variable in `~/.bashrc` to point to new NDK folder location. Restarted terminal.

Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

Below commands did the work.
1. sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
2. sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
3. $ echo 'export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-ndk' >> ~/.bash_profile

Now you may run the brew command:
brew install android-ndk

Answer (score 0):

1 Install NDK

- Open SDK Manager: Android Studio "Preferences" dialog, under Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK → SDK Tools
- Select NDK and Apply
  [image]

2: Set NDK to local.properties
When SDK installed it is the same path with SDK and insert to local.properties files with the exact version
[image]